# NodeJS package.json dependency from github

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a nodejs project, and a dependency:

> https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Usually i used package.json for manage my dependencies, but jsPDF isnt in npm, can i download it from github directly in package.json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You sure can.](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#Git-URLs-as-Dependencies)

You can specify the repository as `username/repo` or use a full URL such as

```
git://github.com/user/project.git
```

So in your case it'd be

```
"dependencies": {
  "jsPDF": "MrRio/jsPDF"
}
```

Also jsPDF is a client-side dependency. Meaning it won't work in Node.js and will only work in the browser, which is why it isn't in NPM, because it's not a Node.js module.

Comment: I have this error:

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/var/folders/pg/c27d18sn72x0kj3w7xm7hzlw0000gp/T/npm-62590-LzdWVmxm/1400669796361-0.9027906500268728/package/package.json'

Comment: I will use in angularjs client. I was think it was server-side library. Thanks you.